# context does not exist when using kubefwd

Tags: kubernetes

When I use `kubefwd`, I hit context does not exist error. But I do have such context, I can even get pod in that context. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

```
➜  user1 git:(master) ✗ sudo kubefwd svc
2019/05/17 17:03:44  _          _           __             _
2019/05/17 17:03:44 | | ___   _| |__   ___ / _|_      ____| |
2019/05/17 17:03:44 | |/ / | | | '_ \ / _ \ |_\ \ /\ / / _  |
2019/05/17 17:03:44 |   <| |_| | |_) |  __/  _|\ V  V / (_| |
2019/05/17 17:03:44 |_|\_\\__,_|_.__/ \___|_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|
2019/05/17 17:03:44
2019/05/17 17:03:44 Version 1.8.2
2019/05/17 17:03:44 https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd
2019/05/17 17:03:44
2019/05/17 17:03:44 Press [Ctrl-C] to stop forwarding.
2019/05/17 17:03:44 'cat /etc/hosts' to see all host entries.
2019/05/17 17:03:44 Loaded hosts file /etc/hosts
2019/05/17 17:03:44 Hostfile management: Original hosts backup already exists at /Users/jzhang/hosts.original
2019/05/17 17:03:44 Error generating REST configuration: context "k8s-e2e" does not exist
```

Comment: Hi , you can check the current context `kubectl config current-context`

Comment: Yes，I checked that，the context exist

Comment: you might try `sudo -e` or `sudo kubefwd -c /Users/jzhang/.kube/config svc`.